# sed command to merge two or more lines which has same keyword

Tags: unix, sed

I have a input file.txt like below

```
ABC
Job: Farmer
DEFG
Job: Plumber
Job: Teacher
GHIJ
```

I want to combine all rows which has Job into one as below

```
ABC
Job: Farmer,Plumber,Teacher
DEFG
GHIJ
```

I tried below way which is not helping

`sed '$!N;/Job: /s/\n/,/ file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/((Job: )\S+)(( \S+)?) \2(\S+) /\1,\5\3 /;ta' file
```

Iterate through each line, using back-references to format as required.

Since the OQ has been amended, a new solution is needed:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x;:a;s/(.*(Job: )\S+)(.*)\n\2(\S+)/\1,\4\3/;ta' file
```

N.B. The iteration in the 2nd solution works backwards through the file since the `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(Job: )(.*)\1([^\n]*)\n/\1\3,\2/;ta' input_file
ABC
Job: Plumber,Teacher,Farmer
DEFG
GHIJ
```